# Understanding design pattern use case

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns

I am a beginner in Design Patterns. Here are some of my use cases where I want to know which design pattern could have been used

1. Firefox which is supported in different OS. The framework would have been the same, With the application layer which shows/renders on the Desktop would be different for different OS. Just want to know which design pattern would perfectly fit for it.
2. Creating widgets for applications on QT tool which can be used/installed across different OS. Does this scenario supported by Factory Pattern or Abstract Factory Pattern.

Would also like to know if more than one design pattern is used in the above scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Is not describing a design pattern but an architectural pattern named [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC). This is because of the different views but same logic code. It is true that it is often used with the [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern, but not required.

[image]

2. Abstract Factory pattern because it is not known exactly what kind of widget will be built.

Answer (score 0):

1. While `MVC` pattern is used as mentioned by FunctionR, multiple patterns are in play.  One pattern that could be used is a `Abstract Factory` or `Factory Method`; where the abstract factory will be parametrized for the given operating system.   And while `MVC` certainly is a pattern it isn't a classic gang-of-four pattern and you could actually decompose it down into underlying pieces.  `MVC` usually involves the `Oberserver` pattern for example.
   Another pattern `Bridge` is often used because it lets you create two seperate hierarchies, one supporting the logical notion of windows, another capturing the implementation details.
2. Similar scenario as the first one; although you will most likely combine the two together.
   It's also noteworthy that QT doesn't exactly use `MVC` but uses a `Model/View` Architecture, combining the `Controller` with the `View`.

Comment: `FunctionR, he is incorrect in stating that other patterns aren't or can't be used.` I never stated that, nor did I imply it. Still, MVC is a pattern but an Architectural pattern not a design pattern.

Comment: Updated sorry about that. Just trying to bridge the gap between the two